# Update a span in a ng-repeat using ng-keyup

Tags: angularjs

In a repeater and I display some records with some data, input field and a span tag in each row. When the user enters numeric value into the input field, 
I want to do a calculation on it and display the result in the `span` tag. This will happen on keypress using `ng-keyup`

I’ve tried this but its not working, probably becuse I'm not using the model correctly...

```
<div ng-repeat="bet in $ctrl.bets">
<input class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="$index" type="text" ng-keyup="$ctrl.getReturn($index)">
<span>Return: </span><span id="$index" ng-model="$index"></span>
</div>
```

And in my controller I have this

```
vm.getReturn = function(index){
document.querySelector('#' + index ).html(value / 2);
}
```

I know its way off, but can someone tell me how to do this? Ta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st thing you can use `ng-model` only with `input`, `select` & special bootstrap components, Not `span` element. You could use `ng-bind` do bind value one way.

Other thing is don't play with `$index` which is added & managed by `ng-repeat` directive itself. I'd say rather add new property inside `bet`(each element of `bets`).

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="bet in $ctrl.bets">
  <input class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="bet.myValue" type="text" ng-keyup="$ctrl.getReturn(bet.myValue)">
  <span>Return: </span><span id="$index" ng-bind="vm.getReturn(bet.myValue)"></span>
</div>
```

Accordingly manage calculation in `getReturn` function.

```
vm.getReturn = function(val) {
   return (val > 0 ? (val / 2): 0);
}
```